# Multiple Ajax submit, same Form ID

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a page with a table of nodes each one with it's own submit button. When pressed the button should call a custom ajax function which creates a cookie with the corresponding orm ID as its value.

My code:

```
function custom_cart_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){      
    if ((stristr($form['#form_id'], 'uc_product_add_to_cart_form')) != FALSE){                      
        $form['#submit'][] = 'set_custom_cookie';
    }

    return $form;
}

function set_custom_cookie($form, &$form_state){
    user_cookie_save(array($form['#form_id'] => TRUE));     
}
```

However, when the set_custom_cookie() function is called it receives the last value of $form['#form_id'] and not the ID of the corresponding form.

To clear things up: if I add the following at the end of hook_form_alter() :

```
function custom_cart_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){      
    if ((stristr($form['#form_id'], 'uc_product_add_to_cart_form')) != FALSE){                      
        $form['#submit'][] = 'set_custom_cookie';
    }

    $form['#form_id'] = "test123";  //Added this line to demonstrate the issue
    return $form;
}
```

then function set_custom_cookie() will receive "test123" on call as the value of $form['#form_id'].

How can I make set_custom_cookie() receive the corresponding form ID?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the form id from the `$form_state` variable as `$form_state['build_info']['form_id']` inside your submit handler.